# what is the problem if we got ER_UNKNOWN_COM_ERROR

Tags: mysql

I've got this mysql Error: 1047 SQLSTATE: 08S01 ER_UNKNOWN_COM_ERROR error from mysql. I've try to search in google. but I didn't find the solution.

Maybe you can help me....

Thanks,

Comment: when exactly do you get this error?

Comment: i'm trying to setup datasource connection pooling in websphere application server. I've set the JDBC provider mysql and the implementation class is com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource. While I trying to test connect the datasource to its JDBC Provider, This error occurred Failed to connect to the DataSource.  Encountered SQLException with SQL State = 08S01, Error Code = 1,047 : Unknown command.

Answer (score 0):

If you describe a little more the situation, maybe we can find something...

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/error-handling.html